# How to change file export numeration?

Tags: export

I'm exporting each frame of my animation as an obj with the animation export option.

Blender automatically outputs all the numerated files however it adds 0s before the numbers.

Example:
run_000001.obj
run_000002.obj
...
run_000522.obj

I cannot find any setting to remove the 0s, I'd like for it to export them:
run_1.obj
run_2.obj
...
run_522.obj

Answer (score 2):

use `#` to define how many decimals you want.
I think you have to export them in steps to avoid the padding  with zeros

from frame 1 to frame 9 use `#.obj`
frame 10 to 99 use `##.obj`
frame 100 to 999 use `###.obj`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

refining the answer from @user2816

Just use a single # eg //renders/#.png to render files with no zero padding, eg. 0.png, 10.png, 100.png

There's no need to render several frame intervals for different number lengths.

Tested in Blender 3.4

[image]